# What would happen to an immobile object in a car if the car turns a corner at a consistent velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Say there is a marble in the center of the floor of my car. It is immobile. The car is going at a consistent speed of 14m/s. The car turns right, keeping that speed. Where would the ball go: would it stay in place because the speed hasn't changed, would it roll to the front because of Newton's first law, or would something else happen?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying "turns right with constant velocity" is a contradiction.  Velocity comprises both magnitude (aka speed) and direction.  The initial velocity of the car is "14 m/s, North" (for instance), and this velocity is shared by everything in the car, including the marble.

The car's velocity after the turn is made is "14 m/s, East" which is a completely different velocity.  If the marble is not secured to the car, the marble will continue its "14 m/s, North" velocity until it hits a wall of the car.  If there is no wall, as in a flat bed truck, the marble will leave the truck and continue on its way North. This is because the marble continues at the same velocity (speed and direction) unless acted upon by an external force, eg via the wall of the car. This is Newton's First Law.

Answer (score 1):

The marble would continue to go in the initial  direction,( we call this inertia) so in the car it will move to the left (and forward) if the car turns right . It is really easy to try it out with a marble on the floor.